# Can we set up 2 water pumps such that they never run simultaneously?

Tags: plumbing, pump, water-tank

We are planning to install 2 water pumps, with 2 overhead tanks. Water outflow of these tanks will be different,  so the pumps will mostly run at different times. Pumps are triggered based on water level controllers in the tanks. There could be a time when both may start simultaneously or one may start when the other is still running.  We want to avoid this (because we want the output of both pumps to go through one single sand filter, but we don't want water to mix).

Is there a way to ensure the pumps never run together?

Comment: Put a lockout relay in the supply to each pump, triggered by the other pump.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "we want the output of both pumps to go through one single sand filter, but we don't want water to mix"? How do you get two water flows to pass through the same filter without mixing? Do you mean there are three-way valves before and after the filter that join the two flows before the filter and split it again afterwards?

Comment: Not planning anything too complex. Just that these are 2 different sources of water, borewell and rainwater (collected from clean rooftop). We don't want them to mix at the same time, but have no issues reusing sand filter, as it gets automatically flushed out regularly.

Comment: Do you expect the output to go to 2 separate destinations, or is it just one output from the sand box?

Comment: Given the nature of a sand filter, the water **is** mixing if you alternate flows through the same sand filter.

Answer (score 3):

There are something called "alternating relays" or "alternating switches", not to be confused with alternators for cars/trucks. The good thing is they aren't a "one off" configuration, they are industry standard. The community water system I helped support used one to alternate between 2 pumps. Worked great.

[image: alternating relay]

https://www.macromatic.com/blog/relays/typical-applications-for-alternating-relays

Comment: I have a similar situation, two sump pumps that I don't want running simultaneously when on generator power.  Alternating relay won't work because the pump switches are integral and submerged.  But thank you for the link. They have something else, a current sensing relay, that might be the basis for a solution.  I'll post a new question over the weekend.

Comment: @jay613 You simply put this relay "upstream" in the power feed.  The pump switch is triggered by a float valve or pressure valve in the holding tanks.  If you route those signals thru the relay, that will ensure that both pumps won't get turned on at the same time.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm not 100% sure what you are suggesting but I think it cannot work.  In my case the switch and "signal" as you put it, are all inside the motor housing underwater.  The only thing exiting that housing is the power cord (and the float arm).  In the diagram in this answer, the "Control Switch" is inaccessible so I cannot route its signal to terminals 1 and 5.  I only have access to the left side of the control switch, that is, the power cord that descends into the water.  The manufacturer makes a similar device using current sensors that I think might work for me.

Comment: At first I agreed with Carl, but thinking more about it, if the controls for the pumps are integral with the pump itself, my solution wouldn't work, unless the OP can find a way to move the control "upstream" as Carl says.  But that also creates the issue of if he wants both pumps to be operated at the same time when NOT on generator power.

Comment: The OP says pumps controlled by water level in the tanks. Controls should be accessible. One DPDT relay for each float, one set of NC contacts for the float, second set of contacts breaking opposite coil circuit. First pump on would disable second. If an override was wanted to run both just throw in a DPST switch inline with one coil on each side and the relays would never energize and open NC contacts. One relay could be eliminated if rain or well is considered primary.